# Sweetalert success message appears even if there's an error

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert

I'm trying to upload a form, if everything is correct it shows a sweetalert success message (this works fine), but if there's an error (Ex. image is too big) it should show the error. The problem is that when there's an error the success message appears an then the error is displayed.

Additional information:
*The database works properly, if there are no error it inserts the new register otherwise it doesn't. 
*I'm using laravel 5.4.

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Programa;
use App;

class ProgramaController extends Controller{

  public function index(){
    return view('programa.create');
  }


  public function store(){

    $this->validate(request(), [

        'titulo' => 'required',
        'poster' => 'required|image|image_size:<=720',
    ]);

    $programa = new Programa;

    $programa->titulo = request('titulo');
    $name=request()->file('poster'). '.' . request()->file('poster')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $programa->poster = request()->file('poster')->move('./uploads/', $name);

    $programa->save();

    return redirect('/');
  }

}
```

My Form

```
<form method="POST" action="/crearPrograma" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit='exito(this.id)'>

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-control">

        <label for="titulo">Título</label>

        <input type="varchar" class="form-control" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="DoQu" required>

    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="form-control-file">

        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="poster" name="poster" aria-describedby="fileHelp" required accept="image/*" >

        <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Póster</small>

    </div>

    <hr>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>

    @include("layouts.errors")

</form>
```

My js

```
<script>
  function exito(id){

    swal({
      title: "Guardado",
      text: "Se ha guardado correctamente",
      type: "success",
      timer: 2000,
      showConfirmButton: false
    });

  }
</script>
```

Comment: `exito` is called right after when you hit the submit button. So put the file size check inside `exito`.

Comment: @Zolbayar I'm doing the validation through laravel in my controller, how can I do it in my js function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your the file size in `exito`. To get it:

```
//filesize would be in bytes
var filesize = document.getElementById("poster").files[0].size;
```

Then:

```
function exito(id){
  var filesize = document.getElementById("poster").files[0].size;

  if(filesize <= 1000000){
    swal({
      title: "Guardado",
      text: "Se ha guardado correctamente",
      type: "success",
      timer: 2000,
      showConfirmButton: false
    });
  }else{
    //show your error here
  }
}
```